# Cakephp with PEAR on Windows Azure Website

Tags: php, cakephp, azure, pear

I am trying to setup an Azure Website that will host my CakePHP website.
Setting up CakePHP was simple enough by choosing the CakePHP template during the creation wizard of the Website.

I tried installing PEAR by following the "PEAR in hosting environments' option, by uploading the go-pear.php file to my webroot folder, and setting the installation path to site/PEAR.

The installation was successful but I get the warning at the end:

> Warning: Can not determine the URL of the freshly installed Web
>   Frontend (file: c:\dwasfiles\sites[MY
>   SITE]\virtualdirectory0\site\pear\index.php). Please access it
>   manually !

In .user.ini that is I put in the site/wwwroot folder, I set the include path to the same folder as I installed PEAR:

> include_path = "C:\DWASFiles\Sites[MY
>   SITE]\VirtualDirectory0\site\PEAR"

But still when trying to use HTTP\Request2 I get the following error:

```
Error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'HTTP/Request2.php' (include_path='C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[MY SITE]\VirtualDirectory0\site\PEAR')
File: C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[MY SITE]\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\app\Controller\RequestsController.php
Line: 2
```

I have spent the last 2 days searching for how to get PEAR working correctly on an Azure website, with no success :(

Can someone please explain how to install PEAR correctly on an Azure website.

Comment: I cannot believe that I have spent the last 2 days trying to install azure-cli, deleted and rebuilt webiste several times, downloaded pear and installed it more than 20 times, and all I had to do was copy over the folder!!! Thanks for pointing out the obvious, everything is working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a remote hosting server it's not about *installing* PEAR but simply *uploading the PEAR folder* from your dev environment, and setting the appropriate `include_path`.

Make sure that `C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[MY SITE]\VirtualDirectory0\site\PEAR\HTTP\Request2.php` really exists.